# What is required to update an autocmd?

Tags: vimrc

From trial and error, to update the following command:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap r ^i#<esc>
```

I have to either:

- (re-)open a python file; or
- Run `:so $MYVIMRC`; then `set ft=python` in that particular order, doing both.

Why are both required, and re-sourcing the vimrc doesn't update everything? Is there a way to re-run the `set ft=self` command automatically when resourcing a file?

Comment: Not sure there's a much better answer than "that's how it works". You need to cause a FileType event to occur and there's a limited number of actions that do that. Usually that means "each time a new or existing file is edited" or someone did `set ft=foo`. But your first bullet implies that your vimrc is getting re-sourced just by opening a file. That surprises me...are you sure? Doesn't seem to behave that way for me.

Comment: Im sure theres an old Q with the answer, but in the meantime a fast way is usually `edit!` (beware of losing changes). `filetype detect` can also help.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble oh that makes it simple, thank you!